# Receive only ONE packet using netcat

Tags: netcat

I would like to use netcat to listen to data and receive only ONE packet. How does one do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `nc`. If you're actually "listening" with `nc`, it's a stream socket, and message boundaries are not preserved, so you cannot be sure that a single read won't be assembled from multiple packets (or vice-versa). If instead you're using the `-u` option to bind to a datagram socket, then **a)** you won't be able to receive any data from clients that use tcp/stream sockets **b)** each read(2) or recv(2) syscall will return a packet, but good luck convincing any shell utility to do a single read (not up to newline, some delimiter or a fixed length).

Comment: Thanks. It is UDP data and I wanted to get one read of the data. socat may be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `nc -ulp 1234 -q1 < /dev/null` to receive just the first one.

It's not great, as it relies on the timeout, but it should work unless your system is completely overloaded. Good enough for a one-off.